# DAL, Session, Cache architecture

Tags: c#, asp.net, architecture, data-access-layer

I'm attempting to create Data Access Layer for my web application.  Currently, all datatables are stored in the session.  When I am finished the DAL will populate and return datatables.  Is it a good idea to store the returned datatables in the session?  A distributed/shared cache? Or just ping the database each time?  Note: generally the number of rows in the datatable will be small < 2000.

Additional info:

Almost none of the data is shared. The parameters that are sent to the SQL queries are chosen by the user. The parameter values available to the user are based on who the user is. In most cases it is impossible for two users to run the same sql queries. However, the same user can run the same query more than once.

More info:
Number of concurrent users ~50,000

Important info:
In 99% of the cases no two users will have the same data/queries, however, the same user may run the same query/get the same data multiple times.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Storing the data in session is not a good idea because:

1. Every user gets a separate copy of the same data - enormous waste of server memory.
2. IIS will recycle a session if you fill it with too much data.

I recommend storing the data tables in [Cache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cache.aspx), and also populating each table only when first requested rather than all at once. That way, if IIS starts reclaiming space in the cache, your code won't be affected.

Very simple example of fetching on demand:

```
T GetCached<T>(string cacheKey, Func<T> getDirect) {
    object value = HttpContext.Current.Cache.Item(cacheKey);
    if(value == null) {
        value = getDirect();
        HttpContext.Current.Cache.Insert(cacheKey, value);
    }
    return (T) value;
}
```

**EDIT:** - Question Update

Cache vs local Session - Local session state is all-or-nothing. If it gets too full, IIS will recycle everything in it. By contrast, cache items are dropped individually when memory gets too low, so it's much less of a problem.

Cache vs Session state server - I don't have any data to back this up, so please say so if I've got this wrong, but I would have thought that caching the data independently in memory in each physical server AppDomain would scale better than storing it in a shared session state service.

Comment: 1. Almost no users will get the same data
2. HttpCache does not work with more than one server.  However, the concept seems a good idea when used with Velocity or something similar

Comment: Cache size is meant to be relatively small, I don't think 50,000 users with multiple datatables in the cache is going to be viable.

Comment: @Joe: True. I guess the best thing to do is not cache any data anywhere to start with, then profile the app to see which tables would benefit most from caching.

Comment: Well, the same user can run the same query multiple times.  i.e. they run the query, switch to a different page/tab run a query, and then switch back and run the same query.

Answer (score 1):

Store *lookups/dictionaries - and items that your app would require very frequently* in `Application` or `Cache` object; query database for data that depends upon the user role.

**--EDIT--**

This is in response to your comment.

Usually in any data oriented system, the queries run around the facts table(or tables that are inevitable to query); assuming you do have a *set* of inevitable tables, so you can use [`Cache.Insert()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa478965.aspx):

1. Load the inevitable tables on app startup;
2. Load most queried tables in Cache upon table request-basis;
3. Query database for least queried tables.

If you do not have any performance issues then let SQL handle everything.

Comment: Wouldn't that be too much data for the cache to handle?

Comment: @subtl3: Well, this really depends upon the amount of data you have. Taking `Note: generally the number of rows in the datatable will be small < 2000` into consideration and your performance constraint... I believe `Cache` is your best bet; even if you'd consider the `Application` object, it wouldn't support the expiration functionality, which is a must in your case.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I would say is: cache is not mandatory everywhere. You should use it wisely and very specially on bottlenecks related to data access.

I don't think it's a good idea to store 1000 different datatables with 2000 records anywhere. If queries are so dynamic that having the same query in a short period of time is the exception then cache doesn't seem a good option.

And in relation to a distributed cache option, I suggest you to check http://memcached.org . A distributed cache used by many big projects around the world.

I know Velocity is near, but so far I know it needs Windows Server 2008 and it's something very very new yet. Normally Microsoft products are good from version 2.0 :-)

Comment: I was looking at SharedCache.  Memcached looked very non-.NET like

Comment: There is a client for .NET http://sourceforge.net/projects/memcacheddotnet/ . It can be used perfeclty from .NET :-)

Comment: AppFabric/Velocity will be released by the end of June.

Answer (score 0):

Storing that amount of data in the `Session` is a very bad idea. Each user will get their own version!

If this is *shared* data (same for all users), consider moving it to the `Application` object.

Comment: Almost none of the data is shared.  The parameters that are sent to the SQL queries are chosen by the user.  The parameter values available to the user are based on who the user is.  In most cases it is impossible for two users to run the same sql queries.  However, if the same user runs the same sql more than once, wouldn't it make sense to avoid that?

Comment: How many users will you have? If not many concurrent users, let SQL manage the concurrency issues. Optimize when you _need_ to, not before.

Comment: At least 50,000 concurrent users

Comment: How often are queries repeated? If only a couple of times, you might as well let SQL handle this.

Comment: Unknown.  It's up to the user.  I'm going to bet more than a couple

Comment: What are the actual performance issues you are seeing? With using sessions, I would expect the web server to run out of memory pretty quickly.

Comment: There are no performance issues right now, because the application is in its development stage.  One user.